# Isoperimetric Inequality : in differentiable $C^1$-case.

Tags: geometry, analysis, fourier-series

I'm studying Fourier series on these days, and I'm going to ask one of them because there are very many blocked parts in the practice questions.

Is is applied isoperimetric ineqality in particular case. I'm very glad if you give me an answer.

The question is like this.

> Differential periodic function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb C $ satisfies these conditions.
>
> - Period of $f$ is $2\pi$.
> - Over the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$, it is injective and $|f'|=1$.
> - n-th Fourier coefficient of $f$ is $\hat{f}(n)$.
>
> Then answer following these question.
>
> 1. **Proove this : Length of the simple closed curve created by the image of $f$ is $2\pi\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}n^2|\hat f(n)|^2$.**
> 2. **Using Green's Theorem, proove this : The area surrounded by this curve is $\frac1{4i} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f'(t)\bar{f(t)}-f(t)\bar{f'(t)})dt$.**
> 3. Proove this : The area surrounded by this curve is $\pi\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}n|\hat f(n)|^2$.
> 4. When is the area surrounded by a curve which has constant length the largest?

I think the 4th problem will be easily done by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality with 1st problem and 3rd problem and it is not clear.

3rd problem is maybe clear, expressing $f'(t)\bar{f(t)}-f(t)\bar{f'(t)}$ as sum of the Fourier series and just integral them.

**So my problem is 1st, 2nd**. I thought about it for a week, but I didn't get any clues.

And I cannot understand. Why Green's Theorem is used here? Wasn't the Green's Theorem is for the line integral?

Comment: Review in your calculus text how Green’s Theorem is applied to compute the area of a region as a line integral over its boundary curve.

Comment: @TedShifrin In the calculus I have studied so far, I have never seen a complex function with real variables. Therefore, I have not seen how to use Green's Theorem in this case. I'm freshmen...

Comment: A complex number is still a pair of real numbers. These are still a region and a curve in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin OK, I'll try end edit this if I solve 2nd problem. And left is 1st problem...

Comment: Edit your question to include how you compute the length of a parametrized curve as an integral and ask a specific question where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a couple hints to help you solve the problem.

**(1):** The arclength of a curve parametrized by $\mathbf{r}(t)=(u(t),v(t)), t\in(-\pi,\pi)$ or equivalently $f(t)=u(t)+iv(t)$ is given by

$$L=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{\left(\frac{du}{dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{dv}{dt}\right)^2}=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|f'(t)|dt=2\pi$$

Because of $|f'|=1$ it is also true that $L=\int_0^{2\pi} |f'(t)|^2 dt$. Expand in Fourier modes to obtain the result.

**(2):** It is a consequence of Green's theorem that the area of a closed curve is given by

$$A=
\frac{1}{2}\oint dt \left(u(t)\frac{dv(t)}{dt}- v(t)\frac{du(t)}{dt}\right)$$

Note however that

$$u(t)=\frac{f(t)+\bar{f}(t)}{2}, v(t)=\frac{f(t)-\bar{f}(t)}{2i} $$

**(3):** As done in (1), expand (2) in Fourier modes.

**(4):** Note that  $n\leq n^2 ~\forall ~n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then it must be true that

$$\sum_n n|\hat{f}(n)|^2\leq \sum_n n^2|\hat{f}(n)|^2\Rightarrow A\leq \frac{L}{2} $$

When does the equality hold here? Which Fourier modes can be non-zero? Determining this should give a simple curve that satisfies the equality constraint.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation! Thanks to your hint, my blockage seems to have been completely resolved.